# why is unset array value acting unexpected?

Tags: php, arrays, unset

From my db I return an array and then want to clean up this array through unset:
My returned array looks like this:

```
Array ( [standard_rate] => 25.00 [reduced_rate] => 20.00 [super_reduced_rate] => 15.00 [zero] => 0.00 [other] => 0.00 )
```

If standard_rate = 25, I want to get this array without the standard_rate so I do:

```
if(standard_rate == 25.00 ) unset($return[standard_rate]);
```

this is not working, or

```
if(standard_rate == '25.00' ) unset($return[standard_rate]);
```

this is not working. However when I do:

```
    if(standard_rate <= 25.00 ) unset($return[standard_rate]);
```

it works.
I also tried:

```
if(zero== 0 ) unset($return[zero]);
```

works as well.
The value of standard_rate in my db is of type double(11,2) and has value 25.00

Why is it that

> if(standard_rate == 25.00 )

is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had errors being displayed, you would see "undefined constant `standard_rate`, assuming `'standard_rate'`". A string. Clearly, `"standard_rate" == 25.00` is false.

```
if( $return['standard_rate'] == 25) unset($return['standard_rate']);
```

Comment: You're right. At first this didn't change anything so it turned out my Array actually was not wat it should be. Now I'm back on track again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if($return["standard_rate"] == 25) unset($return["standard_rate"]);
```

Now let’s see what’s wrong with your code.

`standard_rate` is an undefined constant which has the numerical value `0` and assumed string value `"standard_rate"`, so...

`if(standard_rate == 25.00)` **will not work** because 0 isn’t equal to 25 (numerical comparison).

`if(standard_rate == '25.00')` **will not work** because the strings `"standard_rate"` and `"25.00"` aren’t equal (string comparison).

`if(standard_rate <= 25.00)` **will work** because 0 is less than 25 (numerical comparison).